# Unclear why size is 1 in resultant split list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script for a bigger file.  To check a particular error I wrote this:

```
actual= raw_input(" Enter actual array")
expected = raw_input("Enter expected array")

act = str(actual)
actArr = act.split()
expec = str(expected)
actArr = expec.split()
print(set(actArr).intersection(actArr))
X = (set(actArr).intersection(actArr))
print("%d", len(X))
```

Why does `len(X)` always return 1? Just trying to understand the bug here.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses around the **set** call make the **X** result to be a tuple with a single element: the set you just built.  Remove the parentheses.

In the future, print out the item in question so you can see that you're dealing with.

```
X = set(actArr).intersection(actArr)
```

Also, note that you're taking the intersection of a set with a list (Python doesn't have a built-in "array" type).  What are you expecting from this operation?  Please note that you're taking the intersection of a set with its element-identical list.  I think you want two different items, no?

I'm suspecting that your input has only one element.  **split** defaults to white-space as the separator.  Your comment shows commas, which means that you'd need

```
actArr = actual.split(',')
expArr = expected.split(',')

X = set(actArr).intersection(set(expArr))
```

BTW, you don't have to format every print.  You could do well with merely

```
print len(X)   # Python 2.*; Python 3.* requires the outer parentheses.
```

Comment: Thanks..I did that.but the error seems to be the same SEE:             Enter actual array5,4,6,7,8,9
Enter expected array5,4,6,1,2,3
set(['5,4,6,1,2,3'])
1

Comment: len(X) seems to be giving the same result after these changes. Thanks though.. Any other idea to see the length of "X" ?

Comment: Did you print **X**?  Please update your original question: comments don't show code and data very well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't create a list of Strings using your split call if you don't input the arrays using spaces as delimiters, but keep it one String.

Use

```
actArr = act.split(',')
```

and

```
expecArr = expec.split(',')
```

if you enter it like `'5,6,7,9'`.

Also note that you are comparing actArr with itself...